# Thymeleaf - How to interact and reload Javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Without page refresh, I am calling an ajax request that goes to the controller and brings a  Thymeleaf fragment,

On button click, I request the controller using ajax to get the fragment. Every Time I click on the button same fragment gets called but with a different `<p>` tag `innerHTML`.

```
<div id="express" th:fragment="Display">
<p id="app">Include details about your goals</p>
</div>
```

For the first time, js  works very well, split into an array and add span tag but the issue with the new content which is dynamically replaced.
The issue is on the javascript side when the new fragments with different `innerHTML` inside of the `<p>` tag come the Javascript did not work. I need to refresh the page to re-run the js which I don't want to refresh.

here is the js

```
let comp = document.getElementById("app").innerHTML; 
let struct = comp.split(" "); 

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = struct.reduce((acc, word, index) => {
  return `${acc} <span class="word">${word}</span>`;
}, "");

const handleClick = () => {
axios.post(url)
   .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
           $("#express").replaceWith($recievedHTML);
   })
   .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
   });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why is this question is so up-voted, nothing special and nothing to do with "spring-boot" or "thymeleaf", just regular JS (jQuery) question. You would need to have your JS functions loaded with the main page. When ajax completed and you replaced your content it will be available in the DOM, so just call the functions you need right after `replaceWith`.

Comment: can you give a small example of this? What I want is when a new fragment is replaced by a previous one my js should be reloaded

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes I'll make up some example, but I would need to treat it as the answer (not enough space in the comment section). This answer will not be answering on your direct question "how to reload js?". As I said you just don't need to do this at all, instead the jS functions should be available in the main page and you just need to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your HTML page, which has your JS file or you have added your JS inside `<script>` tag directly. Something like ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script src="/path/lib/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min-dc5e7f18c8d36ac1d3d4753a87c98d0a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/path/js/your_file.min-cf4fcae72d4468307341eac1012bb6d8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="express" th:fragment="Display">
        <p id="app">Include details about your goals</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript for this page may look like ...

```
$(function() {

    function my_load_function() {
        // do your loading procedures here
        // for example I just copied your inline code...
        let comp = document.getElementById("app").innerHTML; 
        let struct = comp.split(" "); 
    
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = struct.reduce((acc, word, index) => {
        return `${acc} <span class="word">${word}</span>`;
        }, "");
    
    }
    
    function my_do_something_else_function() {
        // dosomething else over here
    }
    
    const handleClick = () => {
    axios.post(url)
       .then(response => {
           console.log(response.data);
           // what is '$recievedHTML'? should it be response.data?; 
           // ayway, you said replacement works;
           $("#express").replaceWith($recievedHTML);
           // after this call any function again
           my_load_function();
           my_do_something_else_function();
       })
       .catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
       });
    };
    
    // call your loading function first time
    my_load_function();

});
```

I have put my additional explanation in the comments of JS code. Please note, I just write it directly in SO and didn't even try to run, so there are maybe some typos.

Comment: Ok thank you @Slava Ivanov  so much let me try these  steps